# Trying to compare People Picker entries and Created By on EditForm SP2007

Tags: sharepoint-designer, 2007, jquery, spservices

I am trying to compare the value of a People Picker with the `Created By` on the EditForm. I wish to hide entire rows based on whether the `Created By` equals the People Picker value.

The kink I think, is that on our edit for there are 2 People Pickers, and both People Pickers will have different names in them (or should if the new form was filled out correctly).

My code is simply as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

        var CreatedBy;
        var isMozilla = $.browser.mozilla;
        if (isMozilla) 
        {
              CreatedBy = $("#onetidinfoblock1")[0].textContent.split('by')[1];
        }
        else
        {
              CreatedBy = $("#onetidinfoblock1")[0].innerText.split('by')[1];
        } 



        var Approver = $().SPServices.SPFindPeoplePicker({
             peoplePickerDisplayName: "Approver",
        });



        if (Approver == CreatedBy){
        {
            $("select[title='Approval Status']").parent().parent().parent().hide();
            $("select[title='Decline Nomination: Choice Drop Down']").parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().hide();
        }           
    });
</script>
```

**NOTE:** This is for SP2007. I do have other working jQuery, JS, and SPServices working on the same page.